# Object not found in "geom_signif" function

Tags: r, ggplot2, error-handling, visualization

I want to add significance stars for mean difference comparisons to a plot. Without the lines for the stars, the plot works:

```
da<-data.frame(group=c("condition1_high","condition1_low","condition2_high","condition2_low"),numb=c(30,25,26,20))

da %>% separate(group, c("A", "B"), remove = F) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=A, y=numb, fill = B)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=rep(c("grey20","grey80"), ceiling(length(da$group)/2))[1:length(da$group)]) +
  geom_text(aes(label=numb), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.25) +
  geom_signif(stat="identity",
              data=data.frame(x=c(0.5,1.5), xend=c(1,2),
                              y=c(30, 30), annotation=c("**", "*","***","+")),
              aes(x=x,xend=xend, y=y, yend=y, annotation=annotation))
```

[image: Plot without stars]

Now I add a bit of code for the stars I found here on this platform:

```
da %>% separate(group, c("A", "B"), remove = F) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=A, y=numb, fill = B)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=rep(c("grey20","grey80"), ceiling(length(da$group)/2))[1:length(da$group)]) +
  geom_text(aes(label=numb), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.25) +
  geom_signif(stat="identity",
              data=data.frame(x=c(0.5,1.5), xend=c(1,2),
                              y=c(30, 30), annotation=c("**", "*")),
              aes(x=x,xend=xend, y=y, yend=y, annotation=annotation))
```

Now it says that object B is missing. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `inherit.aes = FALSE` to the `geom_signif` call, otherwise it will try to find a column called `B` in the new data frame you defined. This is because you put an `aes` call inside your initial call to `ggplot`. When you do this, by default all subsequent geoms will inherit the aesthetics and data from this call. If you pass new data to a geom, it needs to include a value for all those aesthetics *or* override the aesthetics *or* you need to switch off inheritance with `inherit.aes = FALSE`

```r
da %>% 
  separate(group, c("A", "B"), remove = FALSE) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = A, y = numb, fill = B)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rep(c("grey20", "grey80"),    
                                 ceiling(length(da$group)/2))[1:length(da$group)]) +
  geom_text(aes(label=numb), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.25) +
  geom_signif(stat="identity", inherit.aes = FALSE,
              data=data.frame(x = c(0.5, 1.5), xend=c(1, 2),
                              y = c(30, 30), annotation = c("**", "*")),
              aes(x = x, xend = xend, y = y, yend = y, annotation = annotation))
```

[image]